# Give gradient to a vertical line in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using a vertical line in my html that I want to give gradient to. I have tried everything but nothing is working for me. Here's my code:

```css
.vline
    {
      border-left: 5px solid green;   /* this green color gets displayed and not the gradient */
      
      background: #67B26F;  /* fallback for old browsers */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 
                                                                26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
      height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="vline"></div>
```

EDIT: The green color that I am defining in border-left gets displayed. The gradient isn't. It should overwrite the previous color.

Comment: What does *"but nothing is working for me"* mean? Your code works great in the SO snippet. Are you using `.vline` in your css? Have you connected your css file to the html file?

Comment: I think the content is lacking since there is no problem with the code. Maybe check if your css file is connected to the HTML file indeed like [s.kuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13573444/s-kuznetsov) has said.

Comment: Check if your ".vline" class is getting over written from somewhere else. Or might you have written twice in your code with different CSS. So this one is not getting priority.

Comment: I did check. The color of the line remains what I defined in my `border-left: 5px solid green`. The color of gradient isn't overwriting the previous color which it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have used pseudo-elements for making the gradient border as per your requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/9noqwj0c/1/

```css
.vline {
  position: relative;
  background: #67B26F;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome                                                         26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


.vline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(219, 85, 83);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219, 85, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(183, 183, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(219, 85, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(183, 183, 25, 1) 100%);

}
```

```html
<div class="vline"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was actually defining the gradient from left to right instead of defining it from top to bottom for such a small width line. :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

call class css in your html tag
html:

```
<div class="vline"></div>
```

css:

```
 .vline{
        width: 7rem;
        border-bottom: 5px solid green;
        background: #67B26F;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F);
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F);
        height: 22rem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `border-left: 5px solid transparent;` instead of `border-left: 5px solid green;`

Answer (score 0):

what's the problem?

```css
.vline
{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F); 
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4ca2cd, #67B26F);
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vline"></div>
```